# How to implement dynamic HTML canvas/frame size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

I have a simple question, I have a html file that has static frame size, for example, if I open this on my 14 inch size monitor, the screen auto scrolls will be enabled, I looking for a functionality that based on screen size, it will auto re-size the frame as well auto center aligning it. I would truly appreciate it, if I could find some information on this, I am a newbee. Thanks

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>testviewdemo4.swf</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
codebase="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" 
WIDTH="1538" HEIGHT="843" id="myMovieName">
<PARAM NAME="movie" VALUE="test.swf"> 
<PARAM NAME="quality" VALUE="high">
<PARAM NAME="bgcolor" VALUE="#FFFFFF">
<PARAM NAME="play" VALUE="true">
<PARAM NAME="loop" VALUE="true">
<PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE="#FFFFFF">
<EMBED src="test.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF WIDTH="1538" HEIGHT="843" 
NAME="myMovieName" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
play="true" loop="true" 
PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
</EMBED>
</OBJECT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: When you ask a question on SO, you need to accept an answer as being "correct". This is done by selecting the check mark next to the correct answer on your question. See [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for details.

Comment: Okay good to know, now Im at 100% thanks